# jq Parse and replace a stringified JSON properties and ignore missing properties

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to convert a bunch of child properties from stringified JSON to JSON.  When the property "c" always exists it works well:

FileZ:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": "x",
      "c": "{\"foo\": 1}"
    },
    {
      "b": "y",
      "c": "{\"foo\": 2}"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$ jq '.a[].c |= fromjson' FileZ
```

Yields

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": "x",
      "c": {
        "foo": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "b": "y",
      "c": {
        "foo": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However when one of the "c" properties above is missing it fails.

```
jq: error (at FileZ:11): null (null) only strings can be parsed
```

How can I ignore this error and instead yield:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": "x",
      "c": {
        "foo": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "b": "y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `.c` exists before feeding it to `fromjson`.

```
.a[] |= if has("c") then .c |= fromjson else . end
```

Comment: Is there a more generalized approach that doesn't require if checks?  For example, if "c" is nested further under the array and one of the parents doesn't exist?

Comment: @tedw See peak's answers. If those aren't what you need update your question to include an example

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more generalized approach ... For example, if "c" is nested further under the array and one of the parents doesn't exist?

You might wish to consider using `walk`:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("c") then .c |= fromjson else . end)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more generalized approach that doesn't require if checks?

The following is a generalized solution without any explicit use of `if`, but it does require [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) version 1.5 or later:

```
(.. | .c? // empty) |= fromjson
```